# Could not cast CLLocation to NSValue - Working with coordinates?

Tags: ios, swift, class, casting, mapkit

I have cloudkit records that are downloaded, each with a location property (lat & long). When I set each record to my `MKAnnotation` Class in a for loop, a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` property, and run... I receive the error as the title states.

This is what I receive -
[image]

Why am I even dealing with an `NSValue` property? I only have coordinates in my class and `CkRecord`.

```
let location = res.value(forKey: "Location") 
print("RUN PLEASE")
self.pin = AnnotationPin(title: res.value(forKey: "Name") as! String, subtitle: "Address", theCoordinates: location as! CLLocationCoordinate2D, theWeb: "https://google.com")
```

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: the pin/annotation line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLLocation` and `CLLocationCoordinate2D` are different types which are not related. However `CLLocation` has a `coordinate` property.

Cast location to `CLLocation` and use `coordinate`

```
let location = res.value(forKey: "Location") as! CLLocation
self.pin = AnnotationPin(title: res.value(forKey: "Name") as! String, 
                      subtitle: "Address", 
                theCoordinates: location.coordinate, 
                        theWeb: "https://google.com")
```

Comment: Vadian, any idea why NSValue was occurring? I missed the location.coordinate  piece, but I tried CLLocation and it continuously brought up the casting issue with NSValue.

Comment: I don't know how `AnnotationPin` is declared.

Comment: CLLocationCoordinate2D

Comment: I have no idea. Some APIs which expect objects (classes) try to use `NSValue` internally to be able to handle structs.